# How to block php errors to be logged in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

How to block the php errors like Severity: Notice —> Undefined variable

to be get logged in **codeigniter** , even by keeping the log threshold level at 3 at config settings.

this scenario occurs due to that all variables are not getting used each and every time.

thanks in advance

Answer (score -1):

```
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_WARNING & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_DEPRECATED);
```

This will suppress all warnings, notice and deprecated(if using php 5.3) messages.